# Java Socket Timesout when I try connecting to server with external IP

Tags: java, sockets

I'm trying to make a simple pong game with multiplayer support, but when I try to connect to the server application with my external ip it fails.

## What I've Tried

localhost, 127.0.0.1, and 192.168.0.10 all work.

When I check to see if my port is open with an external tool it always returns true right away if I have the server running.

[image: My port is open]

Turning off firewall or adding exceptions hasn't helped.

pinging my external IP returns instant response.

## Code for sockets creation in Java and exception

Server Socket Creation

```
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(7777);
for(;;){
    socket = serverSocket.accept();
}
```

Client Socket Creation

```
socket = new Socket(IP, 7777);
```

Exception thrown by client

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at Client.<init>(Client.java:93)
    at Client.main(Client.java:153)
```

Comment: Could you ping to this server?

Comment: @mr.icetea yes I can

Comment: What does your network topology look like (are there any routers, NAT gateways, etc. inbetween your client and server - it might sound like your server is behind a NAT gateway, and you have not configured that gateway to properly forward the TCP ports to your server ) ? Or, what is the IP address of your and what is the IP address of your server, which IP address does your client use to contact the server ?

Comment: @nos Server and Client are running on the same machine

Comment: @DavisEllwood Are you saying you 1. start the server 2. start the client on the same machine as the server, but instruct the client to connect to your external, internet routable IP address  instead of 127.0.0.1 ? If so, I assume you are on a home network, perhaps using DSL, with a box that NATs your local network to reach the internet. If so, your setup usually do NOT work, since most consumer NAT gateways doesn't handle internal devices that tries to connect to the external IP that is port forwared back to the internal network.

Comment: @nos pinging my external ip would be disabled too if that were the case, correct?

Comment: @DavisEllwood No, not at all. Ping is an entirely different thing than NAT'ig a TCP connection. Ping should work. NAT'ing an internal TCP connection through the external IP address usually do not work. This is quite vendor specific, you can make it work with some devices and most high end devices (e.g. cisco/juniper) with the proper configuration, but not your common cheap home router/modem supplied by your ISP

Comment: @nos alright, I'll see if I can get one of my friends to test if they can connect from their device and see how that goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've told us, the setup looks like this:
[image: network topology]

- You have port forwarded port 7777 from *external IP* to *internal IP B*
- Your server listens on *internal IP B* and 127.0.0.1
- Your client successfully connects to *internal IP B*:7777 and 127.0.0.1:7777
- Your client does not connect if you point it to *external IP*:7777

This setup just does not work with most home routers/NAT gateways, they will not port forward a TCP connection destined for the external IP that comes from the internal network itself - it'll only port forward connections that actually comes from the outside(the internet).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to accept the connection client yet?
By accept method from serverSocket

```
boolean isStopped = false;
while(!isStopped){
    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
```

Comment: It wouldn't make any difference if he hadn't. Listening at the port is sufficient for a connect to succeed, firewalls permitting.

Answer (score -1):

Connection time out means your client doesn't get response of its request, possible problems are:

a) The IP/domain or port is incorrect

b) The IP/domain or port (i.e service) is down

c) The IP/domain is taking longer than your default timeout to respond

d) You have a firewall that is blocking requests or responses on whatever port you are using

e) You have a firewall that is blocking requests to that particular host

f) Your internet access is down

Note that firewalls and port or IP blocking may be in place by your ISP

Comment: (a) or (b) would cause 'connection refused', and (f) wouldn't cause a problem at all.